# Find Html Checkboxes

Tags: c#, html

How can I find dynamically generated Html Checkboxes from C#.
Need to find them by id and mark them as checked.

This code generates the HTML first:

```
StringBuilder sbHtml = new StringBuilder("");
sbHtml.Append("<div class=\"checkboxBtn\">");
sbHtml.Append("<input type=\"checkbox\" runat=\"server\" 
                class=\"chkBx\" id=\"" + 
                Convert.ToString(someid) + "\" />");
sbHtml.Append("<label>Compare</label>");                    
sbHtml.Append("</div>");
```

and the rendered HTML is

```
<div class="checkboxBtn">
 <span class="uncheked"></span>
 <input type="checkbox" runat="server" class="chkBx" id="23"></input>
 <label>Compare</label>
</div>
```

There are many such checkboxes and I would like to find them by IDs

```
string[] PhoneIds = {"11","23","43"};
foreach(string id in PhoneIds)
  {
    HtmlInputCheckBox cBox = form1.FindControl(id) as HtmlInputCheckBox;
    if(cBox!=null)
     {
       //cb.checked = true;
     }
  }
```

The if condition always fails as if the checkboxes dont exist. What should be done here.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why aren't you just creating asp checkboxes?(not wrong just asking)

Comment: those are css styles checkboxes & for some reason only working with html and not asp. Tried asp too

Comment: ow weird, cause if i create them, then do Checkbox.id = "chck" than i can change style with css

Comment: So you are building this string of html - fine. How and when do you then add this to the form so that they are available as controls in the code-behind? Hard to say without the rest of the code, but it looks to me like you would be better off with a [`Repeater`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater(v=vs.110).aspx) and check the checkbox in an [`ItemDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Answer (score 2):

you are assigning only one number to your [string-arrey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) PhoneIds:

```
string[] PhoneIds = ["11,23,43"];
```

instead you need to use:

```
string[] PhoneIds = {"11","23","43"};
```

Then you will find them.

Because otherwise you would assign one string to your array, and thisone would be `11,23,43` and as far as you have no checkbox with that string, the if-condition fails.

Also you should not use numbers as ID's, as you can check out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/2354446), where it states that until HTML5

`ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").`

you must start with a letter. Maybe your browser doesn't support HTML5 ?

Comment: sorry that was a typo. I get the IDs fine. not that issue

Comment: @Qwerty Oh okay. Are you using a master-page? And which version of asp.net? Also in which state of the lifecycle do you want to find the checkboxes?

Comment: This is a usercontrol. during postback. asp4.0

Comment: Could you please add a bit more info about your usercontrol? Its hard to understand for me what you do there, do you want to insert the html into a usercontrol and then you reuse the usercontrol somewhere else and you want to find the checkboxes ? Please provide a bit more info.

Answer (score 1):

Element IDs in HTML must not start with a number. That may be why ASP.NET can't find it either. I would put a prefix on it, such as `cbox11`.

To fix the HTML:

```
StringBuilder sbHtml = new StringBuilder("");
sbHtml.Append("<div class=\"checkboxBtn\">");
sbHtml.Append("<input type=\"checkbox\" runat=\"server\" 
                class=\"chkBx\" id=\"cbox" + 
                Convert.ToString(someid) + "\" />");
sbHtml.Append("<label>Compare</label>");                    
sbHtml.Append("</div>");
```

And for the loop

```
string[] PhoneIds = {"11", "23", "43"};
foreach(string id in PhoneIds)
{
    HtmlInputCheckBox cBox = form1.FindControl("cbox" + id) as HtmlInputCheckBox;
    if(cBox!=null)
    {
        //cb.checked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. I added a text 'cbox' but it still doesnt find any checkbox

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check these in the code behind, it can be done in jQuery:

```
<div class="checkboxBtn">
    <span class="uncheked"></span>
    <input type="checkbox" runat="server" class="chkBx" id="23"></input>
    <label>Compare</label>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
        $('div.checkboxBtn input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
   });
</script>
```

This will check all child checkboxes of `div.checkboxBtn`.